# Convert DAO tokens to ether in ethereum wallet

Tags: go-ethereum

I have DAO tokens which I can see on THE DAO account balance page. I'm hoping someone can explain in a step by step procedure how to take my tokens, convert and change them into effect her and deposit them into my ethereum wallet. 
Now I have tried to follow a YouTube video of this procedure but he went to fast and didn't bother to explain which address were to be pasted where. Perhaps to him it was self explanatory but to no techies like myself it was confusing. One wrong mistake and you can loose all your money.  If we want the masses to migrate to the crypto world they need to feel their many is safe.

Thank you